# My cat won't eat food that she normally likes

Tags: cats, diet, feeding, eating, weight

We're in a bit of a weird situation with our cat Rosie (female, 8 years old).  We've had her for most of her life, yet have never seen her refuse to eat her food as much as she has this week.  More specifically:

- Rosie seems to be in good health, though we haven't taken her to the vet in a while.  She's not on any medications.
- Rosie is an outdoor cat; she walks around our neighborhood, but usually comes inside once or twice a day.
- She has *not* vomited, urinated, or pooped any more or any differently than usual, to the best of our knowledge (remember, we don't know where exactly she goes).
- She's lost a fair bit of weight recently, but she doesn't seem any more lethargic or frail than usual.
- This has only really been going on for the past week.

We've tried feeding her the following:

- Several varieties of wet and dry food (mostly fish-based)
- Our dog's food
- Some combination of the above mixed with a special kind of goat milk

And we've tried giving it to her in the following ways:

- Outside, near the door we usually let her in from
- Inside my room (she likes me the most)
- With our other cat temporarily locked in another room (she *hates* him)

Rosie normally eats this stuff.  She'll also eat the following (but we haven't tried it as we don't have any right now):

- Turkey
- Cheese (either real cheese or vegan substitutes--[though we've abandoned the idea of our pets eating vegan](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/11389/6584))
- Leftover fried rice

**Is it possible that Rosie is sick?  Is she being fussier than usual?  Or is she just preparing for a modeling gig we weren't informed about?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change in appetite, and weight loss, are both signs that a pet may be ill. You should consult your veterinarian.

Comment: We wound up ultimately doing this. Let's just say it was a good call.  Thank you for the insight.